# Composer: The package is not available in a stable-enough version error - I do not understand

Tags: github, composer-php

I have a little problem. I created a repository on Github. It has two branch: `master` and `1.1`.

This is the first time when I require my repository.

So I want to get this repository into another project. So I extended the `composer.json` with my github repo name:

```
    "require": {
        // ...
        "botalaszlo/symfony-repositemap-bundle": "dev-master"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
```

But unfortunately I got always a composer error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package botalaszlo/symfony-repositemap-bundle could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

Then I checked the package name, it is fine: copy-paste :)
But the `minimum-stability` problem I do not understand, I think I misunderstand something because I read the links and I still do not find the problem in my settings in composer.json. (However I am tired...).

Then I tried with the `"@dev"`, `"*"`, and with the `"1.1"` values. But always the same problem.

Finally I run the `composer diagnose` command, but it does not see any errors.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The package name has nothing to do with any hosting of the repo on Github or elsewhere.

Go to packagist: https://packagist.org/search/?q=botalaszlo%2Fsymfony-repositemap-bundle If your package cannot be found there, you cannot "simply" use it.

There are some ways to go from here:

1. Add your repo to packagist.
2. Add your repo to the main application manually. [See documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs)
3. Have some private metadata hosted elsewhere just like Packagist, without making that public. [See documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md)